# systemd-resolved does not resolve dns names

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved

So long as I had a single interface up getting its IP from a DHCP server things were working fine. I then connected a second interface and statically configured an IP address on it. Now dns resolution does not work. Setting the new interface down doesnt help either. Tcpdump shows:

> 09:13:47.422879 IP 172.16.0.1.58203 > 127.0.0.53.53: 58631+ [1au] A? [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com). (54)

> 09:13:47.423018 IP 127.0.0.53.53 > 127.0.0.1.58203: 58631 ServFail [0q] 0/0/0 (12)

In the above the source address 172.16.0.1 is the address on the second (now downed) interface.

'resolvectl status' shows:

> Global
> LLMNR setting: no
> MulticastDNS setting: no
> DNSOverTLS setting: no
> DNSSEC setting: no
> DNSSEC supported: no
> Current DNS Server: 10.4.0.11
> DNS Servers: 10.4.0.11
> 172.21.21.51
> 172.21.21.52

The current name server is working as shown in:

> ~$ dig @10.4.0.11 [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com)

> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @10.4.0.11 [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com)
> ; (1 server found)
> ;; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5553
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
> ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;[www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com).            IN  A

> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com).     45  IN  CNAME   new-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com.
> new-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com. 46    IN  A   98.137.11.163
> new-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com. 46    IN  A   74.6.231.21
> new-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com. 46    IN  A   74.6.231.20
> new-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com. 46    IN  A   98.137.11.164

> ;; Query time: 8 msec
> ;; SERVER: 10.4.0.11#53(10.4.0.11)
> ;; WHEN: Wed May 25 09:24:27 PDT 2022
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 138

Any pointers appreciated.

> ~$ uname -v
> #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022

Running on a baremetal server. NetworkManager has been removed from this system.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1410582/edit) and include the distro and version of Linux you are using, and if it is desktop or server version running on a cloud, virtual machine, physical computer, or WSL?

Comment: ~$ uname -v
#49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022

Running on a baremetal server. Network Manager has been removed from the system.

Comment: resolvectl shows status per interface, are you sure you are looking at the correct (old) interface? You mention `172.16.0.1` is down, but tcpdump show otherwise

Comment: The interface is down but for some reason when I do a 'dig' command the dns query uses that address as the source address. I am not sure if it matters because subsequently I removed that address from the downed interface and still cant get the queries to go through.

Comment: For now I have things working by manually overwriting /etc/resolv.conf but would like to know if there is a more graceful way and just what the heck is going on under the covers.

Comment: Found the answer here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466105/iptables-masquerade-breaks-dns-lookups

The issue has to do with ip masquerading.